# FInd the data ids after HTML span and add them to a list (string data)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, pattern-matching

I have a HTML data in string form like this:

```
const text = "<p>Hi <span class="mention" data-index="0" data-denotation-char="@" data-id="58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1ab" data-value="test1 "><span contenteditable="false"><span class="ql-mention-denotation-char">@</span>test1 </span></span> Hi <span class="mention" data-index="0" data-denotation-char="@" data-id="58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1cd" data-value="test2 "><span contenteditable="false"><span class="ql-mention-denotation-char">@</span>test2 </span></span> </p>"
```

I want to extract all the data-id from this data wherever the span class = "mention"

How to do this in javascript?

I was thinking of a regex parser, but is there a easier way to achieve this?

The output will be ["58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1ab", "58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1cd"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) would do:

```js
const ids = [];

document.querySelectorAll('span.mention').forEach(element => {
  ids.push(element.dataset.id);
});
```

Try it:

```js
const ids = [];

document.querySelectorAll('span.mention').forEach(e => {
  ids.push(e.dataset.id);
});

console.log(ids);
```

```html
<p>
    Hi
    <span
        class="mention"
        data-index="0"
        data-denotation-char="@"
        data-id="58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1ab"
        data-value="Test1 "
    >
        <span contenteditable="false">
            <span class="ql-mention-denotation-char">@</span>
            Test1
        </span>
    </span>
    Hi
    <span
        class="mention"
        data-index="0"
        data-denotation-char="@"
        data-id="58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1cd"
        data-value="Test2 "
    >
        <span contenteditable="false">
            <span class="ql-mention-denotation-char">@</span>
            Test2
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

And, if the HTML is stored in a string, we need to parse it using the built-in parser. First, create an element using [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and assign your string to its [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property:

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html;
```

Then, we use the `.querySelectorAll()` method on it, just like what we did with `document` above:

```
div.querySelectorAll('span.mention').forEach(element => {
  ids.push(element.dataset.id);
});
```

Try it:

```js
const html = `<p>
    Hi
    <span
        class="mention"
        data-index="0"
        data-denotation-char="@"
        data-id="58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1ab"
        data-value="Test1 "
    >
        <span contenteditable="false">
            <span class="ql-mention-denotation-char">@</span>
            Test1
        </span>
    </span>
    Hi
    <span
        class="mention"
        data-index="0"
        data-denotation-char="@"
        data-id="58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1cd"
        data-value="Test2 "
    >
        <span contenteditable="false">
            <span class="ql-mention-denotation-char">@</span>
            Test2
        </span>
    </span>
</p>`;

const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html;

const ids = [];
div.querySelectorAll('span.mention').forEach(e => {
  ids.push(e.dataset.id);
});

console.log(ids);
```

Comment: My text value is in a variable called "text" so would my query be 
text.querySelectorAll('span.mention').forEach(element => {
  /* Do what you want with element.dataset.id */
});

Comment: Remember the text is a string variable

Comment: @Sahil Updated. See if it works for you.

Comment: Hi  I used this code:

const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = text;
      div.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(element => {
        console.log("data element:::" + JSON.stringify(element))
      }); but the element value is empty {} Tried with span.mention also

Comment: @Sahil That's because HTML elements are not JSON serializable. Just `console.log()` them without `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @Sahil How did you access it?

Comment: element.dataset.id is working but I think not for multiple span classes

Comment: Like consider this data:
<p>Hi <span class="mention" data-index="0" data-denotation-char="@" data-id="58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a14e" data-value="Ankushpm "><span contenteditable="false"><span class="ql-mention-denotation-char">@</span>Ankushpm </span></span> Hi <span class="mention" data-index="0" data-denotation-char="@" data-id="58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a14e" data-value="Ankushpm "><span contenteditable="false"><span class="ql-mention-denotation-char">@</span>Ankushpm </span></span> </p>

Comment: I get only 1 data element: data element:::{"index":"0","denotationChar":"@","id":"58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a14e","value":"Ankushpm "}

Comment: and it should be 2 as 2 span mention classes are there. is it because of same id?

Comment: I got two elements with same properties and values. Did you see two lines, or just one line?

Comment: Only 1 line I got

Comment: What exactly is the code you're using?

Comment: I think my bad, in the console it was written 2 in front of console line. It is working perfectly. Thanks so much. You are a day saver :) God bless!

Comment: I have a change in requirement actually I want the converted text in this format now: `const convertedtext = "<p>Hi @58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1ab Hi @58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1cd </p>"` only the span classes converted to @data-id @InSync

Comment: @Sahil Please post that as a separate question.

Comment: This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75885966/convert-the-given-html-span-classes-to-data-id, please check

Comment: created another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75887936/change-the-quill-mention-html-span-response-to-concise-data-ids-format @InSync

Comment: Stop adding irrelevant links to this answer. That I answered you once does not mean I'm obligated to do so whenever you post a new question.

Comment: was just adding response to your comment for separate question