# change the quill-mention HTML span response to concise @data-ids format

Tags: javascript, html, replace, quill

I have a HTML data in string form like this:

```js
const text = "<p>Hi <span class="mention" data-index="0" data-denotation-char="@" data-id="58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1ab" data-value="test1 "><span contenteditable="false"><span class="ql-mention-denotation-char">@</span>test1 </span></span> Hi <span class="mention" data-index="0" data-denotation-char="@" data-id="58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1cd" data-value="test2 "><span contenteditable="false"><span class="ql-mention-denotation-char">@</span>test2 </span></span> </p>"
```

I want to convert the span class to `@data-id`. The span output is given by `quill-mentions` library

Example output:

```js
convertedtext = "<p>Hi @58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1ab Hi @58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1cd </p>"
```

I also want to convert the convertText back to original text.

SO to summarize, I want to change the quill-mention HTML response to `@data-ids` for my backend and then revert it back when I am rerendering the values

Related question: [Convert the given HTML span classes to @data-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75885966/convert-the-given-html-span-classes-to-data-id)

Remember I want to replace all the spans with "mention" class. So this is a string replacement question where one pattern has to be changed to another in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of trying, I finally got the solutions:

From string 1 to string 2:

```
let transformedHTML = document.createElement("div");
    transformedHTML.innerHTML = text;
    const mentions = transformedHTML.querySelectorAll("span.mention");
    // Extract the profileIds from each mention
    mentions.forEach(mention => {
      mention.outerHTML = `@${mention.dataset.id}`;
    })
    const newContent = transformedHTML.innerHTML;
    console.log("New content is::" + newContent)
```

String 2 to string 1:

```
let text2 = `<p>Hi @58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1ab Hi @58963f62-3417-481f-9d46-4f5625e9a1cd </p>`;
    const mentionRegex = /(@)([a-z0-9-]+)/g;
    let original = text2.replace(mentionRegex, (match, p1, p2) => {
      return `<span class="mention" data-index="0" data-denotation-char="${p1}" data-id="${p2}" data-value="${p2} ">
      <span contenteditable="false"><span class="ql-mention-denotation-char">${p1}</span>${p2} </span></span> `;
    })

    console.log("Original content is::" + original)
```